# R: nloptr package: both **linear** objective function and **linear** constraint functions can be handled, right?

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nlopt

I am using nloptr. when I read the manual, it say: `g(x)` and `h(x)` are nonlinear inequality and equality constraints.

can `g(x) <=0` and `h(x) = 0` be **linear** inequality and equality constraints, respectively?

Or linear constraints are just a `special case` of nonlinear constraints?

I notice that: in the example of auglag() function, the `heq` belongs to linear equality constraint, so for `nloptr`, it should be OK for linear constraints. From this, even for objective function, the function can be also linear. Please correct me if what I understanding is not right.

```
heq <- function(x) x[1] - 2*x[2] + 1 # heq == 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Yes. A linear constraint is a special case of a nonlinear constraint (with constant Jacobian elements). Some advanced NLP solvers can take advantage of linear constraints.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks. I will give it a try for linear objective function and linear constraints.

Comment: I want to add that usually LP solvers are better in solving LPs than NLP solvers. If that would not be the case there would not be a reason for LP solvers to exist.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen sure. My problem is such case: the objective function is nonlinear, and some constraints functions includes both linear and nonlinear constrains. That is the reason why I ask if `h(x)` and `g(x)` in nloptr package can also handle the linear constraints. I tried some example of linear programming and prove that: `h(x)` and `g(x)` do handle both linear and nonlinear cases.

Comment: The terms linear and nonlinear are not that precise nowadays. Convex and Non-convex is much more important as convex-optimization is in P (algorithmic-complexity; and many real-world problems can be solved in practice; there are some practical limits especially in SDP-optimization though, although it's still convex). If your problem would be convex, specialized solvers (e.g. ECOS, SCS) are favorable.

Comment: @sascha  Thanks. my objective function is convex (nonlinear), but with linear equality constrain and box constraint. Can you recommend solver to deal with this problem.

Comment: I am confused. I see `some constraints functions includes both linear and nonlinear constrains` but also `linear equality constrain and box constraint`. In the first case we have some nonlinear constraints, in the second case only linear constraints.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen The question like this (sorry the format is not good):
    `fn <- function(x, sgm) {
    M1 <- replicate(3, rnorm(3))
    M2 <- replicate(3, rnorm(3))
   M <- list(M1 = M1, M2 = M2)
  res <- Map("*", x, M)
  res <- Reduce("+", res)
  V <- res - 0.1
  base::norm(res - V, "F") + sgm * (base::norm(x, "2") ^ 2)
}`

`heq <- function(x) {
  sum(x) - 1
}

LB <- rep(0, 2)
UB <- rep(1, 2)

x0 <- c(0.1, 0.9)
auglag(x0, fn, gr = NULL, hin = NULL, heq = heq, 
       lower = LB,
       upper = UB,
       localsolver = "LBFGS", sgm = 0.5)`

Comment: Are you sure about this objective. Basically this is `0.3+sgm*sum(x^2)`. Or the same as minimizing `sum(x^2)`. I don't have the feeling you are thinking this through.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen    `J <- base::norm(res - V, "F") + sgm * (base::norm(x, "2") ^ 2)`, where the first term and second term consist of the objective function, `J`. For `V`, it should be other matrix, here I just conveniently put as `V <- res - 0.1` for testing if `nloptr` works or not.